# ¿como puedo centrar los grids items que tienen los stack y todo eso, cuando este en tamaño de telefono?, estoy usando mui ayudenme

Tags: reactjs, grid, mui

Tengo una sección de habilidades en mi aplicación web, implementada con React y Material-UI. La sección consta de una cuadrícula (Grid) que contiene varias cuadrículas internas (Grid items) que contienen avatares (Avatar) y texto (Typography) organizados en pilas (Stack).

El problema que enfrento es que quiero que la sección de habilidades se centre horizontalmente cuando se visualiza en una pantalla pequeña, como en un tamaño de celular. Actualmente, los elementos se alinean hacia el final del contenedor.

Aquí está el código de mi componente:

````
                  container
                  spacing={2}
                  direction="column"
                  textAlign="end"
                  alignItems="end"
                  className="icon-container"
                  
                >
                  <Grid item>
                    <Box>
                      <Typography variant="h2">Language know</Typography>
                      <Stack
                        direction="row"
                        spacing={1}
                        display="flex"
                        justifyContent="flex-end"
                        alignItems="flex-end"
                        marginTop={2}
                        marginBottom={4}
                      >
                        <Avatar
                          sx={{ bgcolor: lime[50], width: 50, height: 52 }}
                          variant="rounded"
                        >
                          <img src={js} alt="JS" width="36rem" />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Avatar
                          sx={{ bgcolor: orange[500], width: 50, height: 52 }}
                          variant="rounded"
                        >
                          <img src={html} alt="HTML" width="36rem" />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Avatar
                          sx={{ bgcolor: blue[500], width: 50, height: 52 }}
                          variant="rounded"
                        >
                          <img src={css} alt="CSS" width="36rem" />
                        </Avatar>
                      </Stack>
                    </Box>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item>
                    <Box>
                      <Typography variant="h2">Frontend</Typography>
                      <Stack
                        direction="row"
                        spacing={1}
                        display="flex"
                        justifyContent="flex-end"
                        alignItems="flex-end"
                        marginTop={2}
                        marginBottom={4}
                      >
                        <Avatar
                          sx={{ bgcolor: lime[50], width: 50, height: 52 }}
                          variant="rounded"
                        >
                          <img src={Mui} alt="Mui" width="36rem" />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Avatar
                          sx={{ bgcolor: grey[800], width: 50, height: 52 }}
                          variant="rounded"
                        >
                          <img src={react} alt="react" width="36rem" />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Avatar
                          sx={{ bgcolor: deepPurple[400], width: 50, height: 52 }}
                          variant="rounded"
                        >
                          <img src={bootstrap} alt="bootstrap" width="36rem" />
                        </Avatar>
                      </Stack>
                    </Box>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item>
                    <Box>
                      <Typography variant="h2">Language know</Typography>
                      <Stack
                        direction="row"
                        spacing={1}
                        display="flex"
                        justifyContent="flex-end"
                        alignItems="flex-end"
                        marginTop={2}
                        marginBottom={4}
                      >
                        <Avatar
                          sx={{ bgcolor: lime[50], width: 50, height: 52 }}
                          variant="rounded"
                        >
                          <img src={js} alt="JS" width="36rem" />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Avatar
                          sx={{ bgcolor: orange[500], width: 50, height: 52 }}
                          variant="rounded"
                        >
                          <img src={html} alt="HTML" width="36rem" />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Avatar
                          sx={{ bgcolor: blue[500], width: 50, height: 52 }}
                          variant="rounded"
                        >
                          <img src={css} alt="CSS" width="36rem" />
                        </Avatar>
                      </Stack>
                    </Box>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>```
````

Comment: Tal vez sea por el `flex-end` que escribiste. Cambialo por `center` dónde sea necesario a ver si resuelve el problema.